# How can I select any outlets randomly and continuously?

Tags: iphone, animation, iphone-sdk-3.0, uiimageview, uiimage

(I have six image view and I want to animate the image randomly for two seconds among them.)

Hello Friends ,
I have six image view with different static images in one view and I want them to animate with the help of

```
img1.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:   
                                    [UIImage imageNamed:imgName],
                                    [UIImage imageNamed:imgName2],
                                    [UIImage imageNamed:imgName],
                                    [UIImage imageNamed:imgName2],
                                    [UIImage imageNamed:imgName],
                                    [UIImage imageNamed:imgName2],
```

method and I want to select the imageview randomly for two seconds.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well to pick a random number from 0,1,2,3,4,5, just do this

```
randomNumber = arcRandom() % 6;
```

To "display for two seconds" you need to learn about NSTimer.  It is quite simple. Here is a simple define that will do something in a period of time:

```
#define SCHED( T, S )                                               \
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:T                       \
        target:self selector:@selector(S) userInfo:nil repeats:NO]
```

So for example:

```
SCHED( 2.0, eliminateImage );
SCHED( 0.5, fadeToBlack );
```

in each case you would have to write the routine "eliminateImage" or "fadeToBlack".

Comment: But How Could I know that I want to animate the image Within the particular imageview outlet ?             i want to pick outlet randomly

Answer (score 0):

this may help you.

```
imageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:IMAGE_COUNT];
for (int i = 1; i <= IMAGE_COUNT; i++)
    [imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Image%d.png", i]]];


bgImage.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithArray:imageArray];
bgImage.animationDuration = 9.0;
bgImage.animationRepeatCount = 0.0;
[self.view addSubview:bgImage];
bgImage.startAnimating;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can select images from array using random index:

```
int index = int index = rand()%[img1.animationImages count];
```